# Octave genetic algorithm not using lower bounds

Tags: octave, genetic-algorithm

Is there a trick to getting Octave's genetic algorithm solver to respect upper and lower bounds? For example,

```
options = gaoptimset('Generations', 10);
nvars = 6;
LB = ones(1,nvars);
UB = LB*10;
[soln, fval, exitflag] = ga(@fitnessfcn, nvars, [], [], [], [], LB, UB, [], options)
```

The solver returns a solution with undetermined bounds. For example,

```
soln = 0.551420   1.369775  -0.313379  -0.038621   0.274696   1.359802
```

UPDATE: I checked the scripts in the Octave package. I am pretty sure the ga function does not use the upper and lower bounds arguments. It does seems to read some upper/lower bound information from the gaoptim set. I'll play around with it when I have some time.

Comment: Hi! If you do find a problem and fix it, could you please submit a patch to the Octave Forge devs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per version 0.10 seems the bounds passed as parameter to `ga` are pretty much ignored. For now the only way to specify a bound is through the parameter `PopInitRange` of `gaoptimset`, which requires a 2xN matrix containing the LBs in the first row and the UBs in the second one. if a 2x1 vector is provided.

The LB and UB parameters are supposed to mimic the original Matlab's `ga` function, but apparently the implementation is taking his own way.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

I can confirm that the parameter bounds are not used by the `ga()` implementation in octave *ga* packet.

### Workaround

I got around this limitation by checking the bounds inside my score function and giving a constant and high penalty score `ParaOutOfRangePenalty` when the bounds are violated. You can implement this similarly in your `fitnessfcn()`:

```
% Your problem specific score calculation goes here:
score = myfitnessfcn(data,parameters);

% Add score for each parameter outside limits to create a "soft" punishment
score = score + sum(parameters(:) < lowerBound))*ParaOutOfRangePenalty;
score = score + sum(parameters(:) > upperBound))*ParaOutOfRangePenalty;
```

### Results

I found that octave `ga()` algorithm is clearly respecting the boundaries using this method.